# How can I create a very dumb QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I need a "dumb" `QWidget` which doesn't do anything, only provides a `HWND` and can be added as a child to other `QWidget`s. Specifically, it should not try to manage the mouse cursor (that is my problem with simply instantiating a `QWidget`). *(motivation: I have an in-place activated ActiveX Control, which tries to change the mouse cursor sometimes, but the QWidget changes it back to the default, so it is flickering)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that does the cursor changing is not within QWidget, so no QWidget changes would fix the problem. It's QApplication that does it, from within the internal `QApplication::dispatchEnterLeave(...)`. Eventually, it is `qt_win_set_cursor` that does the job.

I don't readily see how it'd be possible to change this behavior without changing Qt sources.

I would suggest reporting is as a Qt bug. Qt should be checking if the native cursor was changed upon leaving alien widgets, and if such, would need to preserve it. You'd have better chances of the bug getting fixed quickly if you'd provide a patch to actually fix the issue.

**Workaround:** To prevent flicker, set an application-wide cursor override using `QApplication::setCursorOverride()`. This fixes the flicker but won't fix the control being unable to change the cursor.

Comment: Ah, that's quite disheartening. I'll try to hook on SetCursor and see if I can catch the cursor change. Thanks for the info, when I have time, I may look into making a patch myself for Qt.